# Copy zero string Visual Basic Excel

Tags: string, vba, excel, copy

Here is my problem

```
Worksheets("Worksheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = "28.10"
Worksheets("Worksheet2").Cells(1, 1).Value = Worksheets("Worksheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value
```

And in Worksheet2 i got "28,1".
First question: How i can force VBA to copy zero at the and of string to other cell?
Second question: How i can force VBA to not change dot to comma? This is Polish version office so i guess Excel sees that string as a number so changes dot to comma, becouse comma is a default decimal mark in Poland.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this:

```
Worksheets("Worksheet1").Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat = "@"
Worksheets("Worksheet2").Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat = "@"
```

this will make exel think that in this cell is text (not number) format